# Null Pointer Exception while running code using TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, testng

I am trying to automate a Login and Logout Scenario in TestNG and passing the browser as parameter from XML on the basis of which chromedriver() instance will be created and the code will run.I have two classes TestRunner and Login where login method gets data (username and password) TestRunner and data is fetched from excel.Exception e is getting null value as I found out while debugging. Any way to fix it?

```
FAILED: Registration_data("ashwin@gmail.com", "ashwin123")
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.DataDriven.Login.login(Login.java:68)
at com.DataDriven.TestRunner.Registration_data(TestRunner.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at     org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:12)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
```

---

```
    package com.DataDriven;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    public class TestRunner {

    @Test(dataProvider = "Authentication")
    public static void Registration_data(String sUserName, String sPassword)
        throws Exception {

    Login lp = new Login();
    lp.login(sUserName, sPassword);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] Authentication() throws Exception {

    Object[][] testObjArray = ReadData.getTableArray(
            "F:\\Automation\\DataDrivenPractice\\DataFiles\\DataFile.xlsx",
            "Sheet1");

    return (testObjArray);  }  }
```

---

```
    package com.DataDriven;

    import java.io.File;

    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class Login {
     WebDriver driver = null;

     @Parameters("browser")
     @BeforeClass
    // Passing Browser parameter from TestNG xml
    public void beforeTest(String browser) {

    // If the browser is Firefox, then do this

    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // If browser is IE, then do this

      } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

        // Here I am setting up the path for my IEDriver

        driver = new ChromeDriver(); } }

     public void login(String username, String password) {
        try {
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out")).click();
         }

       catch (Exception e) {
        File srcfile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(srcfile, new File(
                    "F:\\Automation\\Screenshots\\Login.jpg"));
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }   }  }}
```

---

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
        <suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
        <test name="FirefoxTest">
         <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
         <classes>
         <class name="com.DataDriven.TestRunner" />
         <class name="com.DataDriven.Login" /> 
         </classes>
         </test>
         </suite>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I would recommend stepping through this with a debugger, to make sure that `driver` is being set to what you think it's being set to, and to find out exactly which value is unexpectedly null.

Comment: @DavidWallace  Exception e is getting null value. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I've already told you what I recommend for you to do.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, I did debugging and it says Exception e is getting value as null.

Comment: So, before the exception is thrown, which value is unexpectedly null?

Comment: @DavidWallace e is displayed as null in value

Comment: And before the exception is thrown?

Comment: @DavidWallace I think lp but value is not displayed as null

Comment: Please please please indent your code correctly!

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues in your scripts

1 - Your classes init separately. The driver from @BeforeClass doesnot inherite into your @Test

2 - When you do

```
Login lp = new Login();
```

you have

```
WebDriver driver = null;
@BeforeClass is not invoked, no driver init, your driver is still null
```

Then

```
lp.login(sUserName, sPassword);
```

NullPointException throws because driver in following line of code is null

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
```

Suggest action

- You need to get driver goes through all your classes

TestBase.class

```
Put your @BeforeClass here
```

LoginPage.class, be sure you allow to cast driver into it

```
public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    // your code here
}    

// Put login(sUserName, sPassword) method here
```

TestRunner.class

```
inherite/extends from TestBase.class
LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);
lp.login(sUserName, sPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is - your method `beforeTest` doesn't invoke. Your `driver` doesn't point to any type of object.

TestNG search through all your classes only for `@Test` annotation. How it's supposed to know that `@BeforeClass` annotation lies in specific class you've created?

To run `@BeforeClass` annotation, you either have to set `extends` for `Login` class (it won't be effective for multiple scripts) or run `beforeTest` method manually. Or set it to running class containing `@Test` annotation.

Correct me if i'm wrong.
Hope it helps!

EDIT:

Move your method and WebDriver variable to `Test Runner` Class

```
 WebDriver driver = null;

 @Parameters("browser")
 @BeforeClass
// Passing Browser parameter from TestNG xml
public void beforeTest(String browser) {

// If the browser is Firefox, then do this

if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // If browser is IE, then do this

  } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

    // Here I am setting up the path for my IEDriver

    driver = new ChromeDriver(); } }
```

`TestRunner` class should contain both, `@Test` and `@BeforeClass`. As TestNG reads Annotations from classes containing `@Test` annotation.

Comment: You're correct that `beforeTest()` isn't being called, but your reasoning isn't quite right.  TestNG *does* searches classes for annotations, but only  for `@Test`, all other TestNG annotations are inspected after the classes have been found.  Your comment about "setting" `extends` doesn't make any sense; there's no need to extend anything.

Comment: I would still work, tho!

I used to create "Settings" class as a major settings for all `@Tests` and every `@Test` class extended `Settings` class. With this kind of solution, TestNG invokes `@BeforeClass` and `@Test`. 

It's kind of specific solution.

I corrected my answer according to your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to suggest `TestRunner  extends Login`?

Comment: In this particullary scenario it won't be a good solution, but this is what i meant, answering this question.

E.g.: `Login extends BasicSettings` or `TestRunner extends Login`

Comment: I marked my login method as @Test and ran my class now my beforeTest method is getting invoked but now I am getting error as : org.testng.TestNGException: Method login requires 2 parameters but 0 were supplied in the Test annotation. ... Removed 23 stack frames Cant understand why values are not getting supplied, any idea why?